# Adding a new photo to another existing one, creating an album in Facebook

Tags: facebook, album

I have added a photo with comment and would like to add another photo that is on the same topic and have it linked together.

Basically I want to create an album containing these two photos.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an album containing these 2 photos?

Comment: @Barry: yes ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new album with your new photo.

Once you have done this

- go to the existing album that has the picture you want to move.
- Click the `Edit the Album Info` link at the bottom of the album
- Select `Edit Photos`
- Find the picture you want to move and in the drop down on the right hand side select the album you want to move it to.
- Scroll down to the bottom and click `Save Changes`

Your photo should then be moved to your new album.